# How do I create a new branch cleaning up the commits from another branch?

Tags: git, rebase, code-cleanup

I have two branches, `master` and `feature`.

I finished working on `feature`, so this branch have a lot of commits, but I don't want to publish it as is.  I want to create a branch called `feature_clean` with all the modifications from `feature` but with better commits.

I tried the following:

```
git checkout -b feature_clean master
git checkout feature
git rebase --interactive feature_clean
# reorganize commits etc, save and close editor
```

, and this created `feature_clean` correctly BUT it also modified `feature`.  In fact, both branches were equal.

What did I do wrong? I want to keep `feature` as is for now (I'll delete it later, after `feature_clean` is appropriately tested and approved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have your rebase command wrong ;) you are telling git to rebase the current branch (`HEAD`, in that case `feature`) on top of `feature_clean`. I think what you actually want to do is:

```
git checkout -b feature_clean feature
git rebase -i master
```

i.e. replay commits from `feature_clean` on `master`. `feature` will still point to the old commits.

`git rebase master` is shorthand for `git rebase --onto master master HEAD`: take all commits between `master` and `HEAD` (reachable from `HEAD`, but not from `master`) and stick them onto `master`

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout your feature branch
   `git checkout feature`
2. Create your new feature_clean branch
   `git checkout -b feature_clean`
3. Rebase that branch onto where you split off of master
   `git rebase -i --onto shaOfSplit shaOfSplit feature_clean`
4. Do your interactive rebase

At the end of your rebase you will have two branches broken off from the same point.  `feature_clean` will be a rebased version of `feature`